# Overwrite output to file in ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu

I want to overwrite the output of the shell command in a single file on the dockenginx container.

```
perl -pe 's/^server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;/#$&/' default.conf > default.conf
```

I ran the command, but the contents of the default.conf file are all erased.

```
perl -pe 's/^server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;/#$&/' default.conf >> default.conf
```

When I execute this command, the contents are added after that.

What should I do if I want to comment on this phrase "server_names_hash_bucket_size 128" in default.conf?

*External package is not available because it is a dockerginx.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the shell redirection, but why does it work like this? It seems to truncate the file before reading it, working right to left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag `-i` of the `perl` command allows you to edit the file ***inplace***:

> -i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

Now you can use:

```bash
perl -i -pe 's/^.*server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;/#$&/' default.conf
```

Additionally, you can also use `sed -i` instead of `perl -i -pe`

```bash
sed -i 's/^.*server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;/#&/' default.conf
```

`sed` and `perl` are both available inside `nginx` docker container.